# CSS for label drives me crazy

Tags: css, label

Bonkers!

Why does the Label element not align up with everything?
I set all my line-heights to 24px, inline-blocks.

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kMtYN/

```
html { 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', 'Trebuchet MS';
}
.ims-div {
    height: 24px;
    background: gray; 
}
.ims-span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px; height: 24px;
    background: green url('is-check-small-sprite-blue.png') 0 -72px no-repeat;  
}
.ims-label {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; 
    background: purple;
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
}

<div class="ims-div">
    <span class="ims-span"></span>
    <label class="ims-label">CheckBox 1</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/kMtYN/1/

added `vertical-align:middle` to the label and span

Comment: oh my.. and it seems to work in all browsers? Why does the label do that? I tried resetting any default values I could think off. Thanks!!

Comment: the `span` and `label` are behaving differently because span has nothing inside it, while label does.  since there's nothing inside span, line-height takes no effect.  but i'm puzzled as to why the label element has those margins. bizarre.